# Image share to instagram from iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram-api

I am trying to share an image to Instagram  from my  app using `iphone-hook`  using  code below. but after i select **"copy to Instagram"** `UIDocumentInteractionController` just disappears and nothing happens . I don't understand what's going on. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) //check for App is install or not
    {
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image); //convert image into .png format.
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory
        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insta.igo"]]; //add our image to the path
        [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (image)
        NSLog(@"image saved");

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        NSString *fileNameToSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/insta.igo"];
        NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameToSave];
        NSLog(@"jpg path %@",jpgPath);
        NSString *newJpgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",jpgPath];
        NSLog(@"with File path %@",newJpgPath);
        NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:newJpgPath];
        NSLog(@"url Path %@",igImageHookFile);

        self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
        // self.documentController = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];


        self.documentController=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
        NSString *caption = @"#Your Text"; //settext as Default Caption
        self.documentController.annotation=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",caption],@"InstagramCaption", nil];
        [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView: self.view animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *errMsg = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"No Instagram Available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errMsg show];
    }
```